# How can I get the list of my recurring job?

Tags: hangfire

I have try both those line and they all return null.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            //var processingJobs = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi().ProcessingJobs(0, 2000);
            //var processingJobs = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
            return Ok(processingJobs);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var hangfireMonitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

var recurringJobs = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs();
var processingJobs = hangfireMonitor.ProcessingJobs(0, int.MaxValue);
var scheduledJobs = hangfireMonitor.ScheduledJobs(0, int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing my post. Do you know some how i can edit timespan of a schedule job without recreate new schedule job from the beginning. Like by query jobId, I can access the method inside it and pass it to new schedule job, the only thing I need to recreate is time span